# In ggplot2, Why the mean result is a fault one?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data:

```
attitude  order abs rate    
  Neutral   1   16  80% 
  Neutral   1   17  85% 
  Neutral   1   15  75% 
  Neutral   1   14  70% 
  Neutral   1   17  85% 
  Neutral   1   12  60% 
  Neutral   1   20  100%    
  Neutral   1   12  60% 
  Neutral   1   11  55% 
  Neutral   1   14  70% 
  Neutral   1   17  85% 
  Neutral   1   7   35% 
  Blaming   2   12  60% 
  Blaming   2   13  65% 
  Blaming   2   17  85% 
  Blaming   2   16  80% 
  Blaming   2   12  60% 
  Blaming   2   11  55% 
  Blaming   2   11  55% 
  Blaming   2   13  65% 
  Blaming   2   13  65% 
  Blaming   2   12  60% 
  Blaming   2   14  70% 
  Blaming   2   11  55% 
  Insincere 3   9   45% 
  Insincere 3   11  55% 
  Insincere 3   14  70% 
  Insincere 3   16  80% 
  Insincere 3   12  60% 
  Insincere 3   7   35% 
  Insincere 3   16  80% 
  Insincere 3   14  70% 
  Insincere 3   10  50% 
  Insincere 3   16  80% 
  Insincere 3   12  60% 
  Insincere 3   9   45% 
  Commanding    6   9   45% 
  Commanding    6   14  70% 
  Commanding    6   15  75% 
  Commanding    6   9   45% 
  Commanding    6   12  60% 
  Commanding    6   11  55% 
  Commanding    6   12  60% 
  Commanding    6   11  55% 
  Commanding    6   12  60% 
  Commanding    6   3   15% 
  Commanding    6   10  50% 
  Commanding    6   12  60% 
  Prasing   4   14  70% 
  Prasing   4   9   45% 
  Prasing   4   10  50% 
  Prasing   4   12  60% 
  Prasing   4   12  60% 
  Prasing   4   10  50% 
  Prasing   4   12  60% 
  Prasing   4   12  60% 
  Prasing   4   12  60% 
  Prasing   4   9   45% 
  Prasing   4   11  55% 
  Prasing   4   12  60% 
  Polite    5   16  80% 
  Polite    5   14  70% 
  Polite    5   10  50% 
  Polite    5   15  75% 
  Polite    5   16  80% 
  Polite    5   8   40% 
  Polite    5   13  65% 
  Polite    5   4   20% 
  Polite    5   15  75% 
  Polite    5   4   20% 
  Polite    5   10  50% 
  Polite    5   8   40% 
  Friendly  7   6   30% 
  Friendly  7   10  50% 
  Friendly  7   1   5%  
  Friendly  7   10  50% 
  Friendly  7   14  70% 
  Friendly  7   9   45% 
  Friendly  7   11  55% 
  Friendly  7   16  80% 
  Friendly  7   11  55% 
  Friendly  7   9   45% 
  Friendly  7   6   30% 
  Friendly  7   9   45% 
  Sincere   8   4   20% 
  Sincere   8   13  65% 
  Sincere   8   16  80% 
  Sincere   8   4   20% 
  Sincere   8   8   40% 
  Sincere   8   5   25% 
  Sincere   8   11  55% 
  Sincere   8   14  70% 
  Sincere   8   4   20% 
  Sincere   8   0   0%  
  Sincere   8   4   20% 
  Sincere   8   10  50% 
  Joking    9   6   30% 
  Joking    9   9   45% 
  Joking    9   10  50% 
  Joking    9   9   45% 
  Joking    9   4   20% 
  Joking    9   3   15% 
  Joking    9   12  60% 
  Joking    9   10  50% 
  Joking    9   9   45% 
  Joking    9   7   35% 
  Joking    9   7   35% 
  Joking    9   6   30% 
  Hostile   10  5   25% 
  Hostile   10  6   30% 
  Hostile   10  4   20% 
  Hostile   10  10  50% 
  Hostile   10  13  65% 
  Hostile   10  11  55% 
  Hostile   10  6   30% 
  Hostile   10  7   35% 
  Hostile   10  5   25% 
  Hostile   10  5   25% 
  Hostile   10  8   40% 
  Hostile   10  9   45% 
  serious   11  6   30% 
  serious   11  1   5%  
  serious   11  6   30% 
  serious   11  6   30% 
  serious   11  6   30% 
  serious   11  9   45% 
  serious   11  12  60% 
  serious   11  7   35% 
  serious   11  7   35% 
  serious   11  11  55% 
  serious   11  7   35% 
  serious   11  9   45% 
  Rude  12  3   15% 
  Rude  12  4   20% 
  Rude  12  12  60% 
  Rude  12  7   35% 
  Rude  12  10  50% 
  Rude  12  2   10% 
  Rude  12  12  60% 
  Rude  12  7   35% 
  Rude  12  6   30% 
  Rude  12  4   20% 
  Rude  12  5   25% 
  Rude  12  3   15% 
  Suggestion    13  0   0%  
  Suggestion    13  9   45% 
  Suggestion    13  5   25% 
  Suggestion    13  0   0%  
  Suggestion    13  4   20% 
  Suggestion    13  1   5%  
  Suggestion    13  3   15% 
  Suggestion    13  3   15% 
  Suggestion    13  1   5%  
  Suggestion    13  1   5%  
  Suggestion    13  4   20% 
  Suggestion    13  1   5%
```

Here is my code:

```
ggplot (data, aes(x=attitude, y=rate, group=1)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar")
```

While the plot is not right:

1:Many mean results are wrong. i.e. The mean of  "Neutral" is less than 65%, while I counted by myself, the mean of "Neutral" is "72%", obviously larger than the mean indicated in the plot.

Here is the mean result I counted by excel (absolutely right):

```
order   attitude    mean    
1   Neutral 71.67%
2   Blaming 64.58%
3   Insincere   60.83%
4   Commanding  56.25%
5   Prasing 55.42%
6   Polite  54.17%
7   Friendly    46.67%
8   Sincere 38.75%
9   Joking  38.33%
10  Hostile 37.08%
11  serious 36.25%
12  Rude    31.25%
13  Suggestion  13.33%
```

Comment: *Here is the mean result I counted by excel* ????

Comment: Yes, it works for me either. I assume the maximum column in you plot is approximate 65% and the column is "Blaming", right? That is a wrong result, because the maximum column should be "Neutral" and the point should be 71.67% (which I listed below, that is the result I calculated by Excel which should be right). So, I want to know why "stat_summary" function got a wrong result?

Comment: it is wrong because you are feeding it a character vector, do a `str(data)` and you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=attitude, y=as.numeric(gsub("%", "", rate)), group=1)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar") +ylab("rate")
```

#### Update

```
   data$rate <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", data$rate))
   indx <- seq(min(data$rate), max(data$rate), by=10)

  ggplot(data, aes(x=attitude, y=rate, group=1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar") +
  ylab("rate") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=indx, labels= paste0(indx, "%"))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you! One more question, how to change the number of y-axis as percentages (from 0% to 100%)?

Comment: @Ping Tang Updated the plot

Comment: But how to change the ylim from 0 to 100% ?

Comment: @Ping Tang Try `scale_y_continuous(breaks=indx, labels= paste0(indx, "%"), limits=c(0,100))`

Answer (score 0):

The ggplot code works for me after you convert the rate to numeric, note that the attitude order is not the same as in the data.frame. Just fix the order of attitude using factor levels so that it is the same as in the data frame.

```
data$rate <- as.numeric(gsub("%","",data$rate,fixed=TRUE))
data$attitude <- factor(data$attitude,levels=unique(data$attitude))
```

Answer (score 0):

Data worked properly for me. The mean values seem what you want. Why don't you post your graph.
[image]

Comment: I will not tell you that I have no enough reputation!

Comment: I missed that. I think you are not getting correct graph because you are not converting 'rate' to numeric.